# Solana node redownloads every time I restart

Tags: linux, solana

I have a solana node running as a linux service, with a start command similar to:

```
solana-validator --identity ~/validator-keypair.json  --rpc-port 10000 --ledger ~/ledger --limit-ledger-size --log ~/solana-validator.log --no-voting --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001  --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 --expected-genesis-hash <some_hash> --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record --known-validator <some_validator> --known-validator <some_validator> --known-validator <some_validator> --known-validator <some_validator> --dynamic-port-range 8001-8011
```

And anytime my node stops for every a second, it takes up to 30 minutes for it to redownload.

Why is this so?

For specs, my hardware has 2TB of disk space and 300GB of ram.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely killing it (or it is crashing) before it gets a chance to generate a local snapshot.

Comment: I don't see any errors, this can't be it.

Comment: On start up, the logs will tell you if (and why) the validator is not using a local snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

solana-validator --ledger LEDGER_DIR wait-for-restart-window && killall solana-validator